# PushViewController to VC embedded in Navigation Controller

Tags: swift

I am trying to remove all the segues from my project and start using PushViewController.

In one VC I segue to a second VC using this

```
if let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CardDetailVC") as? CardDetailViewController {
        detailVC.cardID = card.key
        navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
    }
```

That VC is embedded in a Nav Cont and the 2nd VC is also.

On an entirely different part I have a VC not embedded in a Nav C, but the VC that I am going into does.

so I tried this

```
if let addVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddCardVC") as? AddCardViewController {
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addVC, animated: true)
}
```

When I tap the button to call this nothing happens. I do not get a crash which is great, but I also do not go to the VC that I want to.

**I have gone to the Storyboard -> VC -> Identity Inspector -> StoryBoard ID and set it to be AddCardVC**

Any idea as to what I am missing?

Comment: R u sure you get into button's action? Add a breakpoint to check.

Comment: @WilliamHu I did, I added a print statement right above it and a breakpoint and it printed

Comment: Check if you set the view controller class is AddCardViewController or not. Identifier is correct or not. The previous segue is deleted or not.

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 From where you are pushing this `addVC` if that controller not having reference of `navigationController` you will not able to push the `viewcontroller`

Comment: Make sure your ViewCotroller need to combined with Navigation controller. Because the PUSH only works when the Navigation controller present in the stack

Comment: 2nd VC no need embedded in a Navigationcontroller check if any warnings in the log.

Comment: @BalaKarunakaran is there a different method if the first VC is not in a Navigation Controller?

Comment: If the view controller you are currently in is not embedded in a navigation controller then self.navigationController will produce nil and therefore you won't get the new view controller presented.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Is there a similar method I can run that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the answers in the comments I decided to embed the first VC in a Navigation Controller. Since I did not want the top bar I added this to the ViewDidLoad

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

and for safe measure I added the opposite to the other VC's =

Comment: Sounds like a sensible solution you get all the navigation control but just hide the bar when you don't want to see it.